# Pass clang vector using ctypes

Tags: python, c, cython, ctypes

I'm trying to convert an existing OpenCL kernel (interfaced with PyOpenCL) to a C->Python extension to get a performance boost over plain python. My OpenCL code heavily relied on float4 and double4, both of which are available with clang using:

```
typedef float float4 __attribute__((ext_vector_type(4)));
```

Preferably, I'd like to send a numpy array to the extension which interprets the array as a vector.

Things I've tried in argtypes:

- Using the pyopencl float4 data type
- Using c_float*4
- ndpointer(c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")

With ndpointer, I'm able to pass numpy arrays to the extension which are then interpreted as pointers in C. However, when I change the function argument datatype from float* to float4* the function just returns 0s for all indicies of the vector.

I'm not sure if I should just switch to Cython or if there's something that I'm missing here.

Comment: Likely a conversion issue from `float4` to numpy array. Since numpy does not understand float4 natively, you'll need to convert it to a numpy array via a conversion function. Could show an example, if example code to replicate is shown.